# php how to send xml responce to file

Tags: php, html, xml

I’m sending XML script to USPS and it responds back to my screen in XML format.  I don’t want it displayed,  I want the response written to a file like “usps_responce.xml” so I can use it later.  In my example below, if I copy and paste the the XML script directly into my browser url it works great, but as I said, I want it written to a file not the screen.  I have tried multiple ways, and this is the best I have come up with so far, I think.  Thanks for any help

```
<?php

$xml = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll?API=RateV4&XML=
<RateV4Request USERID="my_user_id">
<Revision>2</Revision>

<Package ID="1ST">
<Service>ALL</Service>
<ZipOrigination>99016</ZipOrigination>
<ZipDestination>99207</ZipDestination>
<Pounds>40</Pounds>
<Ounces>1</Ounces>
<Container/>
<Size>REGULAR</Size>
<Machinable>true</Machinable>
<DropOffTime>17:00</DropOffTime>
<ShipDate>2018-01-19</ShipDate>

</Package>

<Package ID="2ND">
<Service>ALL</Service>
<ZipOrigination>99016</ZipOrigination>
<ZipDestination>99207</ZipDestination>
<Pounds>5</Pounds>
<Ounces>1</Ounces>
<Container/>
<Size>LARGE</Size>
<Width>7</Width>
<Length>7</Length>
<Height>7</Height>
<Girth>28</Girth>
<Machinable>true</Machinable>
<DropOffTime>17:00</DropOffTime>
<ShipDate>2018-01-19</ShipDate>

</Package>

</RateV4Request>";

file_put_contents("usps_responce.xml", $xml);

$xml2 = file_get_contents("usps_responce.xml");

echo $xml2;
?>
```

If I copy and paste the following script into my web browser

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll?API=RateV4&XML=
<RateV4Request USERID="my_user_id">
<Revision>2</Revision>

<Package ID="1ST">
<Service>ALL</Service>
<ZipOrigination>99016</ZipOrigination>
<ZipDestination>99207</ZipDestination>
<Pounds>40</Pounds>
<Ounces>1</Ounces>
<Container/>
<Size>REGULAR</Size>
<Machinable>true</Machinable>
<DropOffTime>17:00</DropOffTime>
<ShipDate>2018-01-19</ShipDate>

</Package>

<Package ID="2ND">
<Service>ALL</Service>
<ZipOrigination>99016</ZipOrigination>
<ZipDestination>99207</ZipDestination>
<Pounds>5</Pounds>
<Ounces>1</Ounces>
<Container/>
<Size>LARGE</Size>
<Width>7</Width>
<Length>7</Length>
<Height>7</Height> 
<Girth>28</Girth>
<Machinable>true</Machinable>
<DropOffTime>17:00</DropOffTime>
<ShipDate>2018-01-19</ShipDate>

</Package>

</RateV4Request>
```

Then USPS responds back to my screen with the following results similar to the following.  Notice the Rate tag, this one of the variables I need.

```
    <RateV4Response>
<Package ID="1ST">
<ZipOrigination>99016</ZipOrigination>
<ZipDestination>99207</ZipDestination>
<Pounds>40</Pounds>
<Ounces>1</Ounces>
<Size>REGULAR</Size>
<Machinable>TRUE</Machinable>
<Zone>1</Zone>
<Postage CLASSID="3">
<MailService>Priority Mail Express 2-Day&lt;sup&gt;&#8482;&lt;/sup&gt;</MailService>
<Rate>100.20</Rate>
<CommitmentDate>2018-01-22</CommitmentDate>
<CommitmentName>2-Day</CommitmentName>
</Postage><Postage CLASSID="2">
```

Comment: If you don't want it to be displayed on the screen, then why do you use "echo $xml2;" at the end? It looks like you're saving it to a file, then reading it again and displaying it.

Comment: I only echo it in this example to see if there is data in the $xml2, in other words its only for debugging purposes.  In my real website it will not be displayed.  I need it in a variable so I can parse out the variables

Comment: I am not too sure what are you trying to achieve. You want to save a file with the content server-side or you want to give to the user a XML file to download?

Comment: Im trying to calculate shipping costs from US postal service.  When I send the script it responds back to the screen in XML format.  I want that xml response written to a file on the server side, rather than displayed to the screen.  Then I can use PHP to parse the data in the XML file to use  in my shipping costs functions

Comment: but you are already writing the content to an XML file called "usps_responce.xml" and reading it later, the echo statement is printing (or sending to the browser) the content of the file, of course, supposing that your $xml var is a string

Comment: I updated the example code, maybe this will make it more clear.  I want the output written to a file. not the display.  The only reason I echo the string is to see if it scripted worked.  I could always just look to see if the file was created, but temporarily echoing the string to the screen is quicker

Comment: To put it a different way, I am trying to run the xml script within the $xml.  it has a html link followed by xml script.  Then it should respond back by writing the result to a file, not to the screen.  I want it invisible to the user, then I can parse the variable values via PHP from the created usps_responce.xml file at a different time.

Answer (score 1):

The php file_get_contents() function queries data from a file, but instead, you are putting a text string in place of where you need to put a file path.
Set that xml string to a variable then use it as a parameter in the file_put_contents()
E.g:

```
$xml ="your xml string goes here";
 $name_of_file = "ups_response.xml";
 $file = file_put_contents($name_of_file, $xml);
```

Comment: I get [19-Jan-2018 20:46:08 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '808' (T_LNUMBER) in /home/rt133813//usps.php on line 5 which is   <RateV4Request USERID="my_user_id"> in my script

Comment: ok, error is gone, but it is only display script variables before execution, not after.  Please check back in a bit, im going to update my question with more information/example

Comment: What do you mean by:
1. displaying only script variables?
2. before execution, and not after?
Am not sure i quite understand what you mean.